# How to display armatures in front of the object?

Tags: armature

In every tutorial I found the armature renders in front of the object regardless of its depth or mode. In both Edit Mode and Object Mode the armatures are solid grey and always visible.

But my armatures sinks into the object just like any regular object. This makes it impossible to adjust unless I turn on the wireframe mode, which is still difficult due to armatures and model's mesh having the same color until selected. How to make the armatures renders in front of everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select armature, in Properties go to Data>Display and tick X-Ray.

[image]